# Can someone please explain me this Pointer usage?

Tags: c, linux

I am learning  how to code for ARM A9 under Linux. Right now I access some peripherals like LEDS. My code is actually working, but partly based on a tutorial.
The only one part I don't  understand is:

```
  void *virtual_base;
  void *led_addr;
  void *sw_addr;
  int fd;
  int switches;
  switches=*(uint32_t *)sw_addr;
```

`

The part I don't understand is why do I have to write 
    `*(uint32_t *)sw_addr;`

`*sw_addr` means it is a variable, which points to a specific address.In my case it points to specific peripheral register.Reading from this address  will read the status of switches on my board.
But what

`*(uint32_t *)sw_addr`
means? How do you interpret it?
Why I just cant write 
`switches= sw_addr`?

I am bit confused , as you can see.

Comment: `(uint32_t *)` it's a cast, `*` it's dereferencing said object that you just casted .

Comment: `sw_addr` is defined as being a `void *` (a pointer). `(uint32_t *)` this is a cast that now says `void *` is now a pointer to a `uint32_t`. The left most `*` then says to take the integer pointed to by `(uint32_t *)sw_addr` and store it in switches. One thing to note is that it would probably be a good idea to change it to `*(int *)sw_addr` or alter `switches` to be defined as a `uint32_t` with `uint32_t switches` . This keeps the types consistent.

Comment: SO it is better  to define  sw_addr as uint32_t instead of void?

Comment: @user3597998 not always. it depends on the length of the register. you code is reading the register content and storing it in `switches`. i think the best way is define pointers to registers which match the length of corresponding ones.

Comment: Regardless of the casting/reinterpreting going on, since `sw_addr` is never initialized, this code is likely to break anyway...

Answer (score 2):

sw_addr is a `void` pointer. `void` pointers cannot be dereferenced, because void is the no-type type, i.e. there is no such thing as `void a;` as variable declaration. Therefore the pointer is cast to a `uint32_t*`, before it is dereferenced. The value at the address of sw_addr is now interpreted as an `uint32_t, when it is dereferenced.

Edit: I should mention that the specific operation in your code might not be safe, because you are assigning the result to an int (which is signed, whereas the u in `uint32_t` stands for unsigned). An `int` may not be able to represent the number stored in a `uint32_t`, first because `unsigned int`s can store larger numbers, but possibly also because an `int` is not guaranteed to be 32 bits large.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down into steps:

1. `sw_addr` is a variable. The value of the variable is *X*.
2. In the memory, at address X sits some 32 bit (4 bytes) value that you want to read into the variable "switches".
3. `*sw_addr` means "the value at address X", meaning the value that we want to read into "switches".
4. Since `sw_addr` is of type `void *`, we can't write `switches = *sw_addr;` since the compiler doesn't know the size of the data that you want to read. Maybe you're trying to read only one byte, maybe two bytes, maybe four?
5. The casting `(uint32_t *)sw_addr` tells the compiler to look at `sw_addr` as if it were a pointer to a `uint32_t`, meaning a pointer to an unsigned 32 bit value.
6. The statement `*((uint32_t *)sw_addr);` (i've added another pair of brackets for clarity, but it doesn't matter) means the value pointed by our `(uint32_t *)sw_addr` pointer i.e. the 4 byte unsigned value at address X.
7. With the casting in place, we can write `switches=*(uint32_t *)sw_addr;` and it's clear that we intend to read 4 bytes from address X into `switches`.

Alternatively, we could have written the following:

```
uint32_t *sw_addr;
int switches;

switches=*sw_addr;
```

Answer (score 0):

The "for dummies" answer:

```
*(uint32_t *)sw_addr means?
```

It means, give me `uint32_t` worth of data (32 bits) from where `sw_addr` points to.

```
How do you interpret it?
```

`void *sw_addr` points to something of unknown size, it's a `void pointer`. Casting it to a `uint32_t` pointer tells us it points to a `32bit unsigned integer`. Then when we want the data, we get `32 bits` (assuming all casts are correct and can be made).

```
Why I just cant write switches= sw_addr?
```

Assuming you mean `switches = *sw_addr`, it's because it's like saying: Give me unknown amount of data from pointer `sw_addr` (we don't know the type its pointing too).